# What's the right form of verb in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, tense, verbs

I found this sentence in the delivery note.

> Above mentioned Goods **received** in good condition. 
>   We are not responsible for the Goods after the delivery. 
>   Receiver's signature.

My question why do we use the verb "received" and not "were received" or "have been received"?

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question. This is an example of what is sometimes called [headline English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), in which words are omitted to save space when space for a message is restricted. This happens in newspaper headlines, warning posters, information cards, instruction manuals, short notes (as you saw), and so on. Leaving out words like the auxiliary verbs was or has been saves space for other text, and although it makes the sentence not strictly grammatical, it's still understandable.

– user105719